# Shifting a signal in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I would like to know how to shift a signal in Simulink.

I am using a PWM generator (DC-DC) and the input D is from a lookup table, a sine wave. From the PWM generator block I am taking the pulses I want (a sine PWM).

However, because of having two MOSFETs, I need a second pulse signal which should be shifted, so that when the first pulse in the first signal finishes, the first pulse of the second signal starts.

I think the real issue here is this: the duty cycle is changing for each pulse, so each pulse should be shifted by a different time.

The shifting I want is described in the image. The magnitudes of D's are forming a sine wave. For example, if I have 5 pulses (so D1, D2, D3, D4, and D5), the variation of Ds will be like D1=0.1, D2=0.2, D3=0.3, D4=0.2, and D5=0.1 (the numbers are just for example). So I need to shift every pulse according to their own width (duty cycle).

[image: desired shifting]

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is some sort of falling-edge-trigger thing triggered off the first signal, but I haven't the faintest idea how to go about actually doing that...

Comment: How can we do this delay operation by coding in matlab?? Where the delay increases by say 2ms every pulse cycle?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this and the optimum solution will be specific to other details of your model.

Initially try the transport delay block: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transportdelay.html

[Transport delay icon](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transport_delay_block_icon.png)

There is also variable transport delays, unit delays or even constructing more elaborate delay mechanisms via integrators and comparison blocks

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have already tried those blocks. However the output pulses became like triangular shape not rectangular pulses

Comment: That's a simulation setting issue not a transport delay issue. By any chance is the donation continuous with a refinement factor of 1

Comment: Like i wrote down up, i need to shift the every pulses by their own width and every pulse has different(a sine variation, 0 to Dmax to 0 again) width due to being sine PWM. I also tried to use "variable time delay, variable transport delay" but i failed again

Comment: @user391130 could you share a stripdown model. What you describe I do all the time and part of it does sound like a simulation setting issue. Transport delay is all you need. Variable as well due to dependant on the "present" pulse width. However.   When does it start? Because 100% duty could result in a very large buffer... What bounds do you have that can be exploited

Comment: I edit my problem to make clearer about my problem. In the pulses, the max Duty Cycle is less then 50%

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Discrete Variable Time Delay` block as shown in the following example,

[image]

And the result,

[image]

You can adjust the phase shift from the constant (0.5 s in the example).

Comment: Actually it is not my desire. Because i need  to shift the every pulses by their own width and every pulse has different(a sine variation, 0 to Dmax to 0 again) width due to being sine PWM.