# Convert complex number to phase shift in simulink

Tags: signal, signal-processing, simulink

I am currently modelling some dynamic phenomena, combining pure simulink blocks and simscape blocks.

I have measurements (real-valued) on which I perform computations with complex-valued matrices, which give me a complex-valued output.

However, I use this ouput in a feedback loop so I have to convert it back to some real signal for the simulation to run.

My idea was then to convert this complex value that has a relative phase to my input signal into some real signal with same amplitude, but showing a time shift matching the argument of my complex number, but I can't figure it out.

Any suggestions ?

I know of the transport delay / time delay (though I am not sure how to use them in such a situation), but it feels overkill for something that looks so basic. Moreover, I need to perform some linear analysis for stability on this model, which seems to be incompatible with such delay blocks as proposed in [shifting signal in simulink](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/375448/252419).

What is the right way to do this ?

Comment: This is unclear. Is the output a sample sequence where samples are complex numbers? What does the index number of the sequence present (=are the output samples in time or in frequency or in what domain)?

Comment: @user287001, the signals are continuous, there is no numeric processing per se, so no time sample except for the computation step. All signals (input and output) are in time domain.

Comment: Your comment, “...convert this complex value that has a relative phase to my input signal into some real signal...” makes me think of correlation.  Here [is link](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs206/archive/spring02/lab.dir/Lab3/lab3_v3_0_release.pdf).  See section 3.2.3

Comment: @relayman357, thanks for the link. Though it presents an interesting approach, I do not think this is applicable here. In fact, for the correlation to work it seems one has to know the actual frequency of the signal, which is in my case a consequence of the dynamic phenomena I am studying.

Comment: @BambOo  Correlation will let you determine the frequency too.  But, this still may not be what you need here.  See section 3.2.4